# How can i create NSDictionary with multiple array of key and value

Tags: ios, objective-c

i tried to create static JSONArray of value in IOS using Objective -c
 **i want like this**

```
tabledata={
["name":"image 1","path":"img1.jpg"],
["name":"image 2","path":"img2.jpg"],
["name":"image 3","path":"img3.jpg"],
["name":"image 4","path":"img4.jpg"],
["name":"image 5","path":"img5.jpg"],
["name":"image 6","path":"img6.jpg"],
["name":"image 7","path":"img7.jpg"]}
```

this is my data.. please help me any one how can i declare in objective-c..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **dictionary** like below

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
       @"array": @[
           @{
               @"name":@"image 1",
               @"path":@"img1.jpg"
            },
            @{
               @"name":@"image 2",
               @"path":@"img2.jpg"
            }
            ....
        ]
    };
```

and **Array**

```
NSArray *array = @[
           @{
               @"name":@"image 1",
               @"path":@"img1.jpg"
            },
            @{
               @"name":@"image 2",
               @"path":@"img2.jpg"
            }
            ....
        ];
```

For get value from `NSDictionary`

```
NSArray *array = NSDictionary[@"array"]
NSDictionary *firstObj = array[0];
NSString *name = firstObj[@"name"]
NSString *path = firstObj[@"path"]
```

from **Array** just

```
NSDictionary *firstObj = array[0];
NSString *name = firstObj[@"name"]
NSString *path = firstObj[@"path"]
```

Comment: You are welcome, If my solutions is suitable, please mark your question as answered. Thanks

Comment: How can i get value  from NSDictionary array?

Answer (score 1):

One of the alternative old approach is:

```
NSMutableArray *tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary * dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict1 setValue:@"image 1" forKey:@"name"];
[dict1 setValue:@"img1.jpg" forKey:@"path"];

NSMutableDictionary * dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict2 setValue:@"image 2" forKey:@"name"];
[dict2 setValue:@"img2.jpg" forKey:@"path"];

NSMutableDictionary * dict3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict3 setValue:@"image 3" forKey:@"name"];
[dict3 setValue:@"img3.jpg" forKey:@"path"];

[tableData addObject:dict1];
[tableData addObject:dict2];
[tableData addObject:dict3];

NSLog(@"%@",tableData);

//To Fetch Values
NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [tableData objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary1 valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make JsonString to NSDicitonary.

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSData *objectData = [@"{\"2\":\"3\"}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData 
                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                    error:&jsonError];
```

and It is make NSDictionary with array.

```
- (NSDictionary *) indexKeyedDictionaryFromArray:(NSArray *)array 
{
    id objectInstance;
    NSUInteger indexKey = 0U;

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (objectInstance in array)
        [mutableDictionary setObject:objectInstance forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexKey++]];

         return (NSDictionary *)[mutableDictionary autorelease];
 }
```